# How to search with wildcards with RIPGREP

Tags: wildcard, ripgrep

I am failing at using wildcards for words when using ripgrep to find content in my files. Any help welcome.

Specific case: looking for any word stargin with GHJA having any suffix such as GHJA129387 GHJA0938094, etc. (can be letters or numbers).

I tried with GHJA*, but did not work.

Comment: *Any* help? Well, there's the [docs](https://www.mankier.com/1/rg). If you want *specific* help, elaborating your scenario is a good idea -- actual input, desired output, things attempted.

Comment: Fair point. Elaborated more in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use regex with ripgrep, which uses some sort of perl compatible regex (with some caveats for complex cases not relevant to your case, as mentioned in the [docs](https://www.mankier.com/1/rg))

What you need:

```
rg 'GHJA.*?\b'
```

To explain,

- `.*?` is the wildcard – the dot is the quantifier, so we can match any number of characters, the question mark makes the wildcard lazy, instead of greedy.
- `\b` is a word boundary, which you should use because your wildcard is at the end of your search term.